# Woocommerce Set up paypal payment only on digital product and enable visitor to send quote for buying physical product with cash upon delivery enable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to php wordpress woocommerce thingy, so i like to know what are some possibilities to set a specific payment method in this case (paypal) only on my client digital product and let user buy physical product by sending my client the quote within list of item that added to cart or to quote list, as I am going to use this plugin call add to quote from codecanyon:

http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-request-a-quote/6460218?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.z_author=DVin

For sending quote to admin and pay money up on delivery payment method, but since my client are also selling e-book and want to enable paypal payment on only e-book products that why i am asking if what are option that i can get over this challenge. I hope you can help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Login as Admin on your site , In Product option you will see there are two option 
1.Virtual (Like ebook, videos and some other stuff)
2. Downloadable (means when user make purchase then the selected product will be available for download).

Click on  both of the options.
Now there one option will highlight click on Add button 
Add Name and and a link where you have place your ebook.

Your Problem will be resolved